# Search for particular text in txt file and print next line

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, spyder

I am trying to read a text file that contains BEGIN frequently but only once in a line. I have been able to search for it however unable to print the line next to it
if someone could guide me or help me on how to go about this. Below is the code 
Code that i have figured out so far
[image]

the type of file i have
[image]

Comment: why didn't paste the code to here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should put your import statement at the beginning of the file, before any code.

In the process function, you could remove the lines 18 and 19, since the value you give to `a` is overwritten. The method `split` called without any arguments splits the string wherever there is a white space, so if you know for sure that "BEGIN" always is the first word on the line, you could do this (`line = "BEGIN EXAMPLE LINE"`):

`a = line.split()  # a = ["BEGIN", "EXAMPLE", "LINE"]
a = a[1:]  # make a list from the 1:st element to the last, a = ["EXAMPLE", "LINE"]
a = " ".join(a)  # Join all elements in the list divided by white spaces
print(a)  # prints "EXAMPLE LINE"`

or shorter:

`print(" ".join(line.split()[1:]))`

Comment: Thanks @jacob but the aim is once it successfully finds the BEGIN term
Print the the line next to it

Comment: In that case I do not understand what you mean by "line next to it". Is it the lines that come after it you mean, or the line number?